# What does RETURN in a method?

Tags: c#

This is my first day using c#.

I think it is very easy :(.

What does `return` do in this case:

```
 if (flag == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not a number.Re-enter.");
            txtnum.Clear();
            txtnum.Focus();
            return;
        }
```

?

Comment: it returns null then does ... where ... depends if this is a method or not.

Comment: @Ramhound: It doesn't return null.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It simply exits the method. So that no code after that return will be executed.

Answer (score 4):

It bails out of whatever method you're in and returns to the caller.

Answer (score 4):

Return is used as a means of stopping the execution of a method.  Once hit, nothing else in the method will be processed.  It's no different than a function that requires an int to be returned an ends when "return myInt" is hit.  Here, your function returns void, so return alone, without a variable, is sufficient.